# Remove Google Analytics for Development Environment

Tags: google-analytics, web-development

I have a development environment for a website. The environment is an exact clone of the production side, so it's going to have google analytics on it. What's a good way to exclude traffic?

I tried google analytics filters but I think i'm missing something.

**Here's what I tried:**

```
Filters > Predefined
 - Exclude | traffic from the domains | that are equal to, that contain
 - sub.mydomain.com

Filters > Custom
 - Exclude | Hostname
 - Filter Pattern: ^sub\.mydomain\.com
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a condition that looks up the host name, you could have the same code on both production and dev, but on dev you wouldnt display GA code. (PHP: if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'dev.mysite.com') printGACode();)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only a handful of people are going to see the development site you could exclude the IP addresses of those that will visit it. You may still have someone test something on an IP not included but that should get rid of most of the unwanted data, as well as help keep your data from being skewed by you on the live site.